# Of me or for me?It took quite sometime of me to messaged you

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

It took quite sometime of me to messaged you.
I was wondering if it's ok to say "of me" or "for me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example:

> It took quite sometime of me to messaged you

using "of" is incorrect since "me" does not complement "time".

> **Of**:  of is a preposition.  Of commonly introduces prepositional phrases which are complements of
>   nouns, creating the pattern: noun + of + noun. This pattern is very
>   common, especially to indicate different parts, pieces, amounts and
>   groups
>
> **For**:  For is usually a preposition and sometimes a conjunction; use for to talk about a purpose or a reason for something; use for to introduce the person or people receiving something

The correct word would be "for" in this example.

Note:  "sometime" should be separated to "some time", and "messaged" should be "message" in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Use *for me*. It's an idiomatic use of *for*.

Use *some time*. *Sometime* means something else.

Use *to message*, not *to messaged*. It's an infinitive. Infinitives don't have a past tense.

Use either *okay* or *OK*. Don't use *ok*. There's no such word.

End the sentence with a period. In American English it goes before the quotation mark. In British English it goes after.

Comment: you mean like this?
It took quite some time of me to message you. I was wondering if it's OK to say "of me" or "for me." Thanks so much.

Comment: Read the answer again.